How do I cancel the alphabetical sorting of bookmarks in the Opera browser?
The following scenario happened to me.
Having sorted alphabetically in the bookmarks bar in my Opera browser, I need to cancel this sorting due to the fact that, as it turned out, it did not improve my situation, since I mechanically applied it, but later realized that I needed to sort by the date the bookmarks were added, not the alphabet that was suggested by the browser:

In this regard, I have a technical question:

can I cancel alphabetical sorting in the Opera browser if I am not
satisfied with the current situation with the selected sorting.

If so, what steps should I take to revert the bookmarks to their pre-sorting state?
My current version of the Opera browser is a — 112.0.5197.39.
I'm still looking for any workarounds / ways how to avoid the current situation. If I find something, I'll add the answer on my own.
Thank you in advance for any attention to my question.
Also if you need any additional information, please, let me know.

You can't. Once you sort alphabetically, that order is saved in a JSON-formatted file called Bookmarks that you can find in %APPDATA%\Opera Software\Opera Stable\Default.
You would need to have a backup of the file with the old bookmark order. Or you can reorder them manually.
